# SQLAlchemy query not working with functions

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a query that I converted into sqlalchemy format. When I log the query and insert into my IDE to test... it works fine.

```
query= session.query(
            ((func.substr(UserMetrics.START_MONTH, 1, 4)).concat("-").concat(func.substr(UserMetrics.START_MONTH, 5, 6))).label("START_MONTH"),
            UserMetrics.TYPE.label("TYPE"),
            func.avg(UserMetrics_New.SCORE).label("SCORE"))\
        .join(UserMetrics_New,
         and_(UserMetrics.TYPE.in_(('Admin'))))\
        .group_by(((func.substr(UserMetrics.START_MONTH, 1, 4)).concat("-").concat(func.substr(UserMetrics.START_MONTH, 5, 6))),UserMetrics.TYPE)\
        .cte("updated_score")
```

However, when I run in python... I get the following error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression-- still getting this error
```

It turns out that using `func.substr` in the `select` and `groupby` is causing the issue.

`UserMetrics` table has the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.. I want to convert that into `yyyy-mm` format that UserMetrics_New has rows with then do a group by with it.

How can I achieve this?